# Automatic printing from website, to labelprinter and laserprinter

Tags: php, pdf, printing

i'm trying to find a way to print pdf's which are downloaded from our php-based website.

currently  we have to point every printer ourselves ( small labelprinter-large labelprinter-laserjet) , but we would like a workflow like this:

- on the website you click the small label icon.
- a pdf is generated with the label and gets a filename with .pdf stored on the fileserver in the users folder.
- based the prefix and suffix of the file a monitoring program monitoring the folders sends a command to print to the printer specified in the file.

Basically i'm aiming for a kiosk printing mode, with a functionality for every user to specify which printer is nearby and should be used .

Is this a functionality which is easily acheived?

Comment: Easily? I would say not. Achievable? I would say definitely. It depends what exact part of the process you're asking about. Generating and saving a PDF with PHP is fairly easy and straightforward (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php, https://tcpdf.org/, http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en, etc.). The program to monitor and print files would be a tad more complicated - but should still be achievable. That's a bit outside my expertise, but I'd suggest looking into Python: https://www.python.org/

Comment: are you using windows or linux ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in PHP is quite hard, It would be easier to use Python

#### For windows

You have to make a python script which scans every 10 seconds (or less) a folder where you put all files to print.

```
while True:
    files_in_dir = os.listdir(os.path.join('path to the scanned folder'))
    time.sleep(10) # sleep 10 seconds before the new scan
```

Then, you can use [gsprint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm) to send the file to the printer

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['path_to_gsprint.exe', '-printer', 'printer_name', 'fullpath_file'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if out:
    print Tools.format_txt(out)
if err:
    print Tools.format_txt(err, level="error")
```

Once the file is printed, delete it or move it to an other folder so it will not be scanned again.

```
os.rename(filename, 'path to printed folder' + filename) # move file
os.remove(filename) # delete file
```

#### For linux

On linux, the script is quite similar, using Python, you scan a folder and you sent the found files to the printer using `lp` command

```
lp -d PRINTER_NAME *.pdf
```

Again, once the files are printed, delete or move them.

---

With this technique, you will not get instant print, you will have to wait for the script to scan the folder but if you set a short time between scans, this won't be a problem